I want to automate the process of putting the similar name files in a separate folder
I have a list of paths of all the folders in a subfolder , and some path_names have "Chapters"or"Chapter"or"chapter"or even "chaptser" , I want to detect these words present in paths and put these folders in a bigger folder named ALL_CHAPTERS .
Provide with a solution which takes into account that there may be spelling mistakes .
I have something like cosine similarity or kmeans clustering in mind
